# Is there a way to uninstall a SPECIFIC provisioned app for all user accounts in Windows 10 using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, windows-store-app

So I looked up on the web and found PowerShell commands to uninstall:

- All Windows Store apps using PowerShell for all users
- A specific app using PowerShell for current user
- All apps for current user
- All apps from system account/default profile
- All apps for a specific user without logging in to that account

But I see no way to remove a specific provisioned app for all users. Suppose I want to remove only Calculator for all user accounts, how do I do that?

Comment: I have tried the commands here: http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-remove-all-bundled-apps-in-windows-10/ in the past and this: http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-remove-a-specific-bundled-app-in-windows-10-individually/. But there doesn't seem to be a way to remove SPECIFIC UWP app for ALL user accounts? One can remove all apps for all users or 1 app for current user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command (tested with the calculator app on Windows 10 1709):

```
Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -PackageName Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_2017.1201.1912.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe -Online -AllUsers
```

The important part is the `-AllUsers` switch there at the end. This removes the package from all currently existing profiles and deprovisions it so that new profiles won't have it installed. To find the full package name from a fragment, you can use this command:

```
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | ? {$_.PackageName -like '*calc*'} | select -expand PackageName
```